# Pandas convert column with year integer to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am having some problem **converting column (datatype:int64)** into **datetime** working with Pandas.

Original data:

```
Year
2015
2014
...
2010
```

Desired outcome:

```
Year
2015-01-01
2014-01-01
...
2010-01-01
```

My current result:

```
Year
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002015
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002014
...
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002010
```

I have tried:

```
data.Year = pd.to_datetime(data.Year)
data.Year = pd.to_datetime(data.Year, format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `format='%Y'`

```
In [225]: pd.to_datetime(df.Year, format='%Y')
Out[225]:
0   2015-01-01
1   2014-01-01
2   2010-01-01
Name: Year, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

Details

```
In [226]: df
Out[226]:
   Year
0  2015
1  2014
2  2010
```

Comment: Wow, I don't realize that it will convert to that format automatically, thank you! I will accept this answer in 11 mins.

Comment: I do not know why but the ```format``` never works for me when it comes to datetime.

Answer (score 4):

I know this an old question but, there's a catch when converting int to datetime, when the type of the data is int64 it will result in wrong parsing. I had the same situation when trying to convert a list of Years as int64, it would result into:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Year, format='%Y')

Year
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002015 
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002014
...
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002010
```

To avoid this, you need to convert int64 to int32
`df.Year.astype('int32')`. Then you can parse it as `pd.to_datetime(df.Year, format = '%Y')` and you will get the correct output.

```
2015
2014
...
2010
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue, and in my case `pd.to_datetime(df.Year, format='%Y')`,
this worked but not completely. Instead I had to use `.year` at the end of dataframe and voilà! that worked fine.